# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus with two different letters

Tags: definite-integrals

I got a little bit confused on this integral, and the reason is because I got 2 different letters on the function, it tells me to differentiate.

$$F(x)=\int_{5x}^{6x+1}f(x+u)du$$

And I don't know what to do

Comment: Do you know anything about $f(u)$?

Comment: It is continuos.

Comment: It'll help if you write $F(x)=\int_{6x}^{7x+1}f(u)du$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** first off, fix $x$ for a moment and write $t = x+u$. Doing that change of variables will leave you with a different integral, with new limits

$$
F(x) = \int_{r(x)}^{s(x)}f(t)dt = \int^{s(x)}_0f(t)dt - \int_0^{r(x)}f(t)dt 
$$

and these terms can be computed via the theorem you know and a little extra work.

Comment: Are you using the variable change theorem?

Comment: Yes, in its simplest form. I'm substituting $t = x+u$ with $dt = \frac{d}{du}(x+u)du = du$.